# Is GAN a good (better ?) solution for text generation?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Since Karpathy article about RNN (http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/) I saw a few projects and papers about new evolutions in natural language processing but I found nothing about text generation, nothing that bring it to a state where the generated text have a meaning, on the long term.

An then I saw some GAN projects on Github, for text generation. Are GANs a good (better ?) way to code a text generator if we're looking for general meaning for a long text ?

Comment: Your question is purely based on deep learning mechanics, which are not a good fit for Stack Overflow. It could also use some improvements before migration.

Comment: I'm not a deep learning specialist, but a user of some projects, so it's a general quesiton and it's not awaiting a pure math answer, just a few line about the how and why, no more.

Comment: Requesting for code is _still_ inappropriate for SO. Please read [what kind of topics can be asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask].

Comment: I'm not requesting for code... just general talk and opinion.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I must have misinterpreted your comment. Nevertheless, the links I mentioned still apply. Please do not ask for a talk or an opinion in Stack Overflow, as it attracts low quality answers. Also, as mentioned from the beginning, pure deep learning questions such as this one are off-topic. Consider visiting [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) and [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com) for those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text Genration is an open research topic and has been for a long time. In contrast GAN research is in its infancy, with many problems plaguing the topic like mode collapse, vanishing gradient and general difficult of training. It is not proven that a solution to the gan problem exists and if that is even desireable.

Still, GANs have been applied to text generation with promising results (http://proceedings.mlr.press/v70/hu17e/hu17e.pdf), albeit not state-of-the-art results. The question is what do you want to do? Do you want to advance the state-of-the-art in text generation? Then GANs is one direction you can go to advance the field. If you just want to generate text for your own application I would go with a more proven approach.

Comment: I'm using those tools in artistic projects so we are quite open considering the results. From this position I'm enthusiast and really curious, that's why I asked about GANs in text generation, for getting a general view and collecting opinions.